# Read a term-document matrix from csv using python

Tags: python, csv, term-document-matrix, large-data

The reason classic csv reader doesn't work on term-document arrays is that the first column of the csv file are terms, not values. Thus the file has the following syntax:

```
"";"label1";"label2";"label3" ...
"term1";1;0;8;...
"term2";0;0;3;...
.................................
```

I need to build a dictionary whose keys are label1, label3, etc... and values are the column vectors (here it would be: dict[label1]-> 1,0 , dict[label2] -> 0,0 etc), meaning that the terms are completely useless to me.

I have implemented a custom solution which goes something like this:

```
....
keys = f.readline().split('";"') #1st line of the csv
keys = keys[1:]                  #skipping ""
zeros = [0] * len(keys)          #dicts initial values will be 0
d = OrderedDict(zip(keys, zeros))
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    ...
    splittting, stripping etc I get a list with values (eg: 1,0,8 - see example above)
    ...
    for value in values:
        ....
```

However reading 8 csv files (total: 12MB) takes over 90 minutes with my laptop.

Does anyone know a more efficient way to deal with this?

Comment: Why do you need an `OrderedDict` here exactly?

Comment: have you considered loading the file with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and then iterating through the columns and rows to make the dictionary that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `csv` module anyway to read the CSV files into memory, then transpose the rows using `zip(*rows)` or `itertools.izip(*rows)`:

```
with open(somecsv, 'rb') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=';')
    headers = next(reader)
    data = list(reader)
    data = dict(zip(headers, zip(*data)))
```

This creates a `data` dictionary with the headers as keys and the columns as values. You can delete the `''` 'terms' column from the dictionary if needed.

For your input example, the `data` dictionary looks like this after executing the above code:

```
{'': ('term1', 'term2'), 'label1': ('1', '0'), 'label2': ('0', '0'), 'label3': ('8', '3')}
```

Comment: isn't it `reader.next()`? I get this if I do `next(reader)`: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration`

Comment: @RyanSaxe: `next()` is a function that'll call `reader.next()`; on Python 3 you'd have to call `reader.__next__()`, the `next()` function is the proper API to use. You have opened an empty file or have *already* read all the contents of the file; `reader.next()` will raise `StopIteration` *too*.

Comment: Superb! 90+ minutes became 5-6 seconds! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

pandas is clearly the way to go! All you have to do is load the dataframe into a dictionary and it makes one. Here is all the code, it's quick and efficient:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(filename)
my_dict = dict(data)
```

quick and easy!